# Eliminate types of elements from the list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have list where only zeroes and other list elements are present. How can I eliminate only zeroes?

List is generated by:

```
xvar = Array[x, {n + 3, m + 3}, {{-2, n}, {-2, m}}] /. 
       x_[i_, j_] /; j > 0 -> 0
yvar = Array[y, {n + 3, m + 3}, {{-2, n}, {-2, m}}] /. 
       x_[i_, j_] /; j > 0 -> 0
vars = Join[Flatten[xvar], Flatten[yvar]]
```

I tried:

```
DeleteCases[vars, 0, Infinity]
```

but it deleted also indices of the x and y arrays.

Then I tried:

```
Assuming[{x[i_, j_] != 0 /; i > 0, x[i_, j_] != 0 /; j > 0, y[i_, j_] != 0 /; i > 0, y[i_, j_] != 0 /; j > 0}, vars2 = Table[If[vars[[i]] == 0, Nothing, vars[[i]]], {i, Length[vars]}]]
```

But it does not work - behaves as if the assumption is not there and leaves items like ''If[x[0, -2] == 0, Nothing, vars[[i]]]'' and is also cumberstone, I need some more filtering for xvar and yvar to apply.

Comment: Maybe `Pick[vars, NumericQ /@ vars, False]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works:

```
Select[vars, # =!= 0 &]
```

It selects elements in vars that are not `0`.
Your attempt with `DeleteCases` failed because of `Infinity`. Try `DeleteCases[vars, 0, 1]` instead, or equivalently

```
DeleteCases[vars, 0]
```

But this approach is apparently more computationally efficient:

```
Cases[vars, Except[0]]
```

For $m=k=1000$, the first command runs in `0.75` seconds, the second in `0.26` and the third one in `0.14`.

**Edit** For completeness, coolwater's suggestion `Pick[vars, NumericQ /@ vars, False]` returns the same result after `0.36` seconds.